# Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.8 <a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a> Affected Modules

Tags: android

guys.

I'm new to android development and there is a problem.

Somehow I cannot sync jetbrains library anko although I followed what they've written on their github.

Here are the error code and build.gradle.

Please help me.

I want to use anko library.

Error code

Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.8
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Project gradle

```
projects/modules.
buildscript{
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.8'
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

Module gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.won.kotlinpractice'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.won.kotlinpractice"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the wrong Anko implementation

Please check this and use required please find details [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko).

```
dependencies {
    // Anko Commons
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

    // Anko Layouts
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:$anko_version" // sdk15, sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"

    // Coroutine listeners for Anko Layouts
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25-coroutines:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"

    // Anko SQLite
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"
}
```

Note :  Anko is deprecated. Please see this [page](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md) for more information.

Comment: I've just copied what you've typed here.
What I got are 6 failed resolve messages.